# Count Number of Characters in a Mixed String of ASCII and Unicode

Tags: php, unicode, ascii

```
strlen($username);
```

Username can carry ASCII, Unicode or both.

***Example:***

**Jam123 (ASCII)** - 6 characters
**ابت (Unicode)** - 3 characters but strlen returns 6 bytes as unicode is 2 bytes per char.
**Jamت (Unicode and ASCII)** - 5 characters (3 ASCII and 2 Unicode even though i have only one unicode character)

Username in all cases shouldn't go beyond 25 characters and shouldn't be less than 4 chars.

**My main problem is when mixing Unicode and ASCII together, how can i keep track of count so the condition statement can deicde whether username is not over 25 and not less than 4.**

```
if(strlen($username) <= 25 && !(strlen($username) < 4))
```

3 characters in unicode will be counted as 6 bytes which causes trouble because it allows user to have a username of 3 unicode characters when the characters should be minimum of 4.

Numbers will always be in ASCII

Comment: All ASCII is Unicode. Not all Unicode is ASCII.

Comment: @tchrist All ASCII is **UTF-8**. Not all **UTF-8** is ASCII. Unicode is neither.

Comment: @user This may be a good read for you: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: @deceze: You’re wrong. ASCII is a subset of ISO-8859-1, and ISO-8859-1 is a subset of Unicode. Unicode is a coded character set.  It maps characters to codes. Its first 128 code points are the exact same code points used by ASCII, another coded character set.  Similarly, all ISO 8859-1 is Unicode, but not all Unicode is ISO 8859-1, insofar as the first 256 code points of Unicode correspond exactly to all code points of Latin-1. Furthermore, while Unicode has code points like surrogates that cannot be expressed in conformant UTF-8, conformant UTF-8 cannot represent a non-Unicode code point.

Comment: @tchrist In terms of actually working with any of these encodings (in bytes) only UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII. The code points may be shared between ASCII, ISO-8859-1 and Unicode. But there's a difference between code points and bytes in Unicode that does not really exist for the other two encodings. You can't say all ASCII is UTF-16, yet UTF-16 is a Unicode encoding. That may be putting a very fine point on it, but when working with encoded strings, ISO-8859 is never the same as Unicode.

Comment: @deceze I try very hard not to work with encoded strings. I prefer decoded strings where everything is an abstract number. To me they are the same.

Comment: @tchrist OK, that's somewhat  unusual though. Also, everything is *encoded* in some form. You just prefer to work with encoded/escaped Unicode code points in ASCII encoding then... :o)

Comment: @deceze: To the contrary: working with completely decoded, logical, abstract, integral Unicode code points is the **desired norm**, as it the only sane way to deal with Unicode. It is also what is required by UTS#18 on regular expressions. Dealing with serialization schemes is dog-work where you have to worry about stupid little code units, not real code points. It is a recipe for continuous disaster. And UTF-8 is **not in ASCII**, because ASCII is 7 bits and UTF-8 has 8-bit code units. **SHEESH!!!**

Comment: @tchrist This comment field to too small to completely explain our difference in communication. In a nutshell, I'm saying ASCII and latin-1 don't have an abstract code point representation, only Unicode does. There's no physical bit representation of Unicode that is compatible with latin-1. Only UTF-8 is bit compatible with ASCII. If you talk about latin-1 being a subset of Unicode, that's only on an abstract level. Since latin-1 does not have an abstract level separate from the encoded byte representation, they're not really comparable. I will leave this argument at this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/mb_strlen). It takes care of unicode characters.

Example:

```
mb_strlen("Jamت", "UTF-8"); // 4
```

Comment: Surprinsly, it worked! I tried this solution before but didn't work...I guess i had a typo or so ... Anyway, little fix mb_strlen() ... Thanks

Comment: Require extra package mbstring: `sudo apt install php-mbstring`

Answer (score 1):

You can use mb_strlen where you select your encoding.

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/3a144/1

```
<?php 
echo mb_strlen('ابت', 'UTF8'); // returns 3
```

Answer (score 0):

function to count words in UNICODE sentence/string:

```
function mb_count_words($string) 
{
    preg_match_all('/[\pL\pN\pPd]+/u', $string, $matches);  return count($matches[0]);
}
```

or

```
function mb_count_words($string, $format = 0, $charlist = '[]') {
    $string=trim($string);
    if(empty($string))
        $words = array();
    else
        $words = preg_split('~[^\p{L}\p{N}\']+~u',$string);
    switch ($format) {
        case 0:
            return count($words);
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
            return $words;
            break;
        default:
            return $words;
            break;
    }
}
```

then do:

```
echo mb_count_words("chào buổi sáng");
```